# Highest viewed Puzzle all time?

Tags: feature-request

Is there any way to check Highest viewed puzzles all time ? Like a ranking based on number of views .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SEDE is your friend](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/876987/most-views).

From the above query:

1. [Two doors with two guards - one lies, one tells the truth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2188) (690,947)
2. [Puzzle of putting numbers 1-9 in 3x3 Grid to add up to 15](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1957) (303,566)
3. [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 = 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/12187) (234,484)
4. [Crack the lock code](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/46871) (187,464)
5. [What is the number of the parking spot?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1797) (166,791)